# How to make DGEMM execute sequentially instead of in parallel in Matlab Mex Function

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, openmp, blas

In Visual Studio, I can set the MKL (DGEMM BLAS) library to execute sequentially so that I can write the OpenMP parallelization codes myself. How can I do the same in a Matlab Mex function so that I can write the OpenMP parallelization the way I want it? Any help on this will be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: mkl_set_num_threads() in C or MKL_NUM_THREADS environment variable.